# Event Emitter CallBack in function runing

Tags: react-native, events, eventemitter

I'm triggering an event using the EventEmitter, and I can't run the methods inside the class I used in this event. where do I do wrong and how can I solve this problem?

```
    StaticBase.emitter.addListener('event', this._updateEvent);

_updateEvent(value) {
    if (value.length > 3) {
        this.setState({ keys: value });//---->ERROR function not found, etc .. errors
        this.UpdateList();
    }
}

UpdateList() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    console.log('POST------>>');
    axios.post('.........')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ newlist: response.data });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }).catch(ex => {
            console.log(ex);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        });
}
```